# Writing a method query to display specific list of users - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am unsure how to go about writing the below method, your help would be much appreciated. what i am trying to do is:

- if a user has stated they are male (`category_gender_id = 1`) and that they are seeking a female (`user.preference.category_matchseeking_id = 2`) i would like to then display all female members with a `category_gender_id = 2`
- `category_gender_id = 1` [male]
- `category_gender_id = 2` [female]
- `category_matchseeking_id = 1` [male]
- `category_matchseeking_id = 2` [female]
- **Question**: could one kindly advise me how i write the method `preference_list` correctly for it to be displayed correctly in the views (users/index.html.erb) to display users that are females if current user is a male or vice versa? - tried the below but does not seem to work

> models

```
user.rb
  belongs_to :category_gender
  has_one :preference

  def self.preference_list
    users = User.all
    users.each do |user|
      if user.preference.category_matchseeking.name == "Male"
        #display users that are female
        users.joins(:category_gender).where('category_genders.name' => "Female")
      else user.preference.category_matchseeking.name == "Female"
        #display users that are male
        users.joins(:category_gender).where('category_genders.name' => "Male")
      end
    end
  end
```

--

```
Preference.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :category_matchseeking
```

--

```
CategoryGender.rb
has_many :users
```

--

```
CategoryMatchseeking.rb
has_many :preferences
```

> Views [users/index.html.erb]

```
 <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <td>gender</td>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>stats</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @users.preference_list.each do |user| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= link_to user.firstname, user %></td>
          <td><%= link_to user.lastname, user %></td>
          <td><%= user.category_gender.name%></td>
          <td><%= user.email %></td>
          <td>-</td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying your `else` statement as `elsif`:

```
if user.preference.category_matchseeking.name == "Male"
  #display users that are female
  users.joins(:category_gender).where('category_genders.name' => "Female")
elsif user.preference.category_matchseeking.name == "Female"
  #display users that are male
  users.joins(:category_gender).where('category_genders.name' => "Male")
end
```

This `else user.preference.category_matchseeking.name == "Female"` will be interpreted like if is equal or not.

And your `self.preference_list` could be used as a helper method within your `ApplicationHelper` or the model helper as:

```
def preference_list
  users = User.all
  ...
end
```

And then used within your views just as `<%= preference_list %>`

Also I think you can use the `where` statement as `where('category_genders.name = Female')`, not with `=>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I believe you're looking for something like this.
Assuming you have a current_user method to get the current user

```
def preference_list
   @users = Users.where(category_gender_id: 
   current_user.category_matchseeking_id, category_matchseeking_id: 
   current_user.category_gender_id)
end
```

this method will find all of the users that are looking for your gender_id and are the gender_id you're looking for.